# read from socket stops on last byte

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, streaming

server.c

```
bytesReceived = 0;
    char buff[256];
    char* buffFile;
    char tempbuff;
    bytesReceived = read(clnt_fd, &tempbuff, 1);
    buffFile = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    buffFile[0]=tempbuff;
    long incr=1;
    while(bytesReceived > 0 )
    {

        bytesReceived = read(clnt_fd, &tempbuff, 1);
        incr++;
        buffFile = (char*)realloc(buffFile, sizeof(char)*incr);
        buffFile[incr-1]=tempbuff;

    }
```

client.c

```
char filebuff[20];
strcpy(filebuff, "UPC ");
strcat(filebuff, file_size); //it's the file size
strcat(filebuff, " ");

write(clnt_fd, filebuff, strlen(filebuff));


while(1)
  {
  int nread = fread(file_bytes,1,256,fp);
  bytesSent = write(clnt_fd, file_bytes, nread);

  if(bytesSent<0) 
    {
      printf( "Error: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
      break;
    }
  if(nread<256)
    {
        char t='\n';
        bytesSent = write(clnt_fd, &t, 1);
        break;
    }

}
```

So basically, the client will send a message like this and i must put a '\n' as the last byte.

```
UPC 5624 bytesbytesbytesetcetc\n
```

And the server shall receive those bytes that I put in an array in order to tokenize it and get those bytes from the array to write it in the file. The problem is, I've made a counter, I saw how many bytes were sent from the client, and how many bytes are being received each time a loop ends, and I've checked that on the last byte, my server blocks on read function and hangs there. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You keep reading forever, so eventually it will block until more data arrives, an error occurs, or EOS, which will never happen as the peer isn't closing his end. And why are you reading one byte at a time? Do a single read, into a buffer large enough to hold what you're expecting, and loop if you didn't get it all.

Comment: I don't know how much data will arrive. I'm receiving files, and their size can be enormous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a C++ guy, but seems that before you enter the while-loop, you execute a 'read'. And when you enter the loop you execute 'read' again, that's seems a bit strange.

Also do the 'incr++;' at the bottom of your while loop scope. Because you start with an offset of 1 already. And before you read/use incr, you increment incr already.
Then you don't have to do incr-1 in the buffer array (because you also missed the first element of bufFile[0] in the first iteration of your while loop )

Just mentioning it, don't know this solves your question (answering this with mobile phone keyboard...)